Model Fit Measures in a Binomial Logistic Regression
I am very new to regression statistics and have produced four models in the statistical package Jamovi using binomial logistic regression. Looking at model fit measures I am confused as the results seem contradictory. I will summarise the contradictions below:
Model 1
AIC 138
BIC 144
df 1
Chi squared 46
p < .001
Model 2
AIC 126
BIC 137
df 3
Chi squared 62.3
p < .001
Model 3
AIC 128
BIC 151
df 7
Chi squared 67.9
p < .001
Model 4
AIC 111
BIC 158
df 15
Chi squared 101.0
p < .001
Model 1 has only one covariate, as a main effect
Model 2 adds a second covariate as a main effect
Model 3 adds a third covariate as a main effect
Model 4 uses the second and third covariates but not as main effects, rather as the interaction between them.
My confusion is that model 4 has the best AIC score and the largest degrees of freedom.. but the BIC is the highest… this is very contradictory and confusing for me when trying to select the best model. Which model selection parameters should I prioritise?

Welcome to CrossValidated! Can you give us some more information about your dataset, like how many observations you have and what your features and the outcome are? In Model 4, are you saying that this includes the interaction but not the main effects? That would usually not be the standard way of modeling.

Hi Stephen. Thanks for your reply. I have 136 observations and I am trying to predict the presence/absence of small predators given various covariates in the environment. I only used 3 covariates. The first 3 models included the three covariates as main effects. The fourth model looked at 1 covariates as a main effect and the other two covariates not as main effects, but as interaction. Is this incorrect

Hm. In model 1, a single df is a bit strange, because you would expect to fit an intercept parameter plus at least one for your covariate. Model 2 has 3 df, which makes sense for an intercept and two parameters for two covariates that are either numerical or factors with two levels. I assume the covariate you add in model 3 has five factor levels, based on the four additional df compared to model 2? Finally, I can't quite get to 15 df in model 4, adding an interaction should be adding 4 df, not 8.

In any case, it's usually standard to not only have the interaction in the model, but also the main effects, take a look at these: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+without+main+effects+is%3Aq. Finally, your model 4 is very large with 15 df for only 136 observations - a very rough rule of thumb is to have at least 20 observations per df, so model 3 is borderline. Can you edit your post to provide snippets of the model summaries?
